# How to prevent showing extra console window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010

I don't know what I switched (if anything) in Windows (7) or Visual Studio (2010), but all my console programs previously run as expected. For example -- I launched cygwin terminal or cmd one, I launched my program, it ran and produced output to the original terminal.

But currently whenever I execute my program extra console windows shows up (yet the output is displayed at original terminal), without any purpose, when the program ends, it is closed.

The trick with switching console program into Windows Application (Visual Studio --> Properties) disables showing extra console but also disables any output from the program. This is not what I want.

*The only thing that I can tell it changed, was changing VirtualBox (my environment is withing VirtualBox). I upgraded it to 3.4 version, and then downgraded back to 3.2 one. Besides that (as far my memory serves me), I didn't change a thing.*

Comment: Could you post a very small example which illustrates a program opening extra console windows?  I'm quite sure some visitors to this website would like this feature.

Comment: @cup, this is an ill side-effect, not a way. Anyway, this code `Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine("done.");` opens extra, dead, console. The writing and reading occurs in the main terminal.

Comment: Does this also happen when you launch your program from the standard command-line shell, `cmd.exe` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yes, directly from Visual Studio too. And one thing, showing this extra dead console takes a lot of time (let's say more than launching 10 `cmd.exe` manually).